# gwt open a new window and post json data

Tags: gwt, post, httprequest

I have a page which has a botton. And I want to click the button and open a new window. And in the same time, I will send post Json data to that request. I know gwt has get method to open a new window like this:Window.open(url, "", ""); But that is not a post method.
So I try to use RequestBuilder. However, that is only an Ajax call. What I want is after I send the post json request, it will get the response(response include the html div) and open a new window. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: I am speaking based on my memory, but I think I have seen this done with GQuery. When I have a chance, I will try, but in the meantime if you do not have any path, try by yourself. The ides is create a window, save the reference using JSNI, and then try to inject data on that variable. Mmmmm maybe using JSNI should be easy as well... Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) to save the state of the user specific data that can be accessed by any page within the same domain.

Steps to follow:

- Simply make a **[GWT RPC call](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html)** to pass the JSON string to the server in post request.
- At server side of RPC call save the JSON string in **HTTP Session** to access it later
- Now open a new page (having *same domain*) that will access the JSON string from the HTTP Session

---

Complete Sample code including GWT PRC classes as well

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("greet")
public interface GreetingService extends RemoteService {
    public void setJSON(String json)throws IllegalArgumentException;
}

public interface GreetingServiceAsync {  
    void setJSON(String json, AsyncCallback<Void> callback);
}

public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GreetingService {
    @Override
    public void setJSON(String json) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // set the JSON string in HTTP Session
        getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().setAttribute("json", json);
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.x.y.z.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/modulename/greet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Entry Point class:

```
GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);
public class GWTProject implements EntryPoint {
    public void openNewWindow(final String json) {
        greetingService.setJSON(json, new AsyncCallback<Void>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                // open any page within the same domain
                Window.open("/page.jsp", "", "");
            }
        });
 }
```